# How to get an image from the database in a custom view?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database and a table in that called 'Recipe', and I manually  added contents to that table. It contain an image column also.

I wanted to display the table and pass it through JSON. I don't know how to display image.

My code is:

```
<?php

include("connection.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM Recipe";

if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    $number = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "<table cellpadding=\'0' cellspacing='0' class='db-table'><tr>
    <th>Recipe name</th>
    <th>Photo</th>
    <th>Steps</th>
    </tr>";
    while($recipe=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$recipe['Recipe_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td><img src='".getImage.php?id=1."' width='175' height='200'</td>" ;

        echo "<td>".$recipe['Recipe_steps']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
} else {

    echo "It failed";
}


 ?>
```

Comment: I don't see `$recipe['image']` anywhere.

Comment: `getImage.php` has issues. Is that a script that generates the image? If so it should be in the quotes, you also want to pass in the specific id.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong. You forgot to put the image url here.
    echo "" ;

You aren't referencing your image URL

```
echo "<td><img src='".$recipe['imageurl']."' width='175' height='200'></td>";
```

the image tag was not closed properly.

Comment: hi,thanks for your reply. I just replace the code which you mentioned but unfortunately it doesnt work.Kindly please check it once again and help me to fix it.

Comment: What is the image url tag called in your Recipe table?

Answer (score 0):

try to change, your missed, to put the image url here.

```
<img src='".getImage.php?id=1."' width='175' height='200'
```

to

```
<img src='".$recipe['imageurl']."' width='175' height='200'>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: hi i tried to replace the code but no change.If you dont mind please explain the need of 'imageurl'